# Specifying length of columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, types

Is there any danger in making a column say, an INT with length of 3 digits and some of the columns only containing one or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [INT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) in Sql Server is 4 bytes so you won't be able to do what you describe. The values can range from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

If you only want to store numbers uf up to 3 digits, a `smallint` will suffice (2 bytes).

Comment: thanks.  i meant to say nvarchar.  how does that change things?

Comment: @DarrinCecil If you are really storing numbers, don't use `nvarchar`

Comment: why is the reason for that?  just takes up more memory i suppose?

Comment: The reason is that you said you wanted an int.  If you choose to store than in nvarchar(3), someone can insert 'abc' and mess up your system.

Comment: @DarrinCecil your logic becomes a nightmare if you use nvarchar to store numbers (you'd have to do conversions to int either in your queries or your programming language,etc.), nvarchar(3) will take even more space than a smallint. There are more reasons why this is bad.

Comment: touche.  in this particular database the general public will only have read-only access and it will be updated yearly, so you make a valid point but in this particular instance i don't think it will matter.  thanks for pointing that out, though :)

Comment: @DarrinCecil, Icarus is right.  Sure, maybe the general public can't insert but you and any other maintenance dev can.  Now the system is not self-documented and someone may eventually put crap in there because they didn't know any better.  A test data generator is going to put crap in there.  I find it interesting that you seem to be concerning yourself with the impacts of storing something so small but are not concerned with type safety.

Comment: @TimLehner it's because I'm still learning right from wrong :).  I was aware that varchar is just a crapshoot, catchall but didn't really think about how deleterious its use could be.

Comment: Gotcha...we're all still learning!  Yes, use types to your advantage.  Computers, generally speaking, operate much more efficiently on numbers than strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make an INT with 3 digits. An INT goes from negative 2 billion to positive 2 billion, and takes 4 bytes unless you are (successfully) using compression.

You could use a `SMALLINT` which will save you two bytes, but in order to keep it to 3 digits, you'd need to add a check constraint where `column < 1000`. You still won't be able to save space on smaller values (e.g. single digits will still take 2 bytes) again, unless you are using compression.

Answer (score 1):

An int has a predefined storage size. You can't change it. [Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

You may be thinking of [numeric or decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) where you can specify precision.

Answer (score 1):

You might choose to use a Decimal type as in the following:

```
create table #MyTable
(
    NotOneThousand decimal(3,0)
)

insert into #MyTable select 999
insert into #MyTable select 1000 -- fails
insert into #MyTable select -999
insert into #MyTable select -1000 -- fails

select * from #MyTable

drop table #MyTable
```

Or use a check constraint such as:

```
create table #MyTable
(
    NotOneThousand smallint check (NotOneThousand between 0 and 999)
)

insert into #MyTable select -1 -- fails
insert into #MyTable select 0
insert into #MyTable select null
insert into #MyTable select 999
insert into #MyTable select 1000 -- fails

select * from #MyTable

drop table #MyTable
```